# Cache lookups on application startup and reuse it in Hibernate entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I am using **Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE** and I am using spring `@Cacheable`
and what I am trying to accomplish is to cache a country lookup on application start-up as follows:

```
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, BigInteger> {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = Constants.CACHE_NAME_ALL_COUNTRIES)
    List<Country> findAll();

}
```

and call it on start-up as follows:

```
@Component
public class StartUpInit {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationReady(ApplicationReadyEvent ready) {
        List<Country> list = countryRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

The obvious thing is that subsequent calls to findAll will load the data from the cache, but what I am trying to do is something like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
public class Project {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
    private Country country;

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = Constants.CACHE_NAME_ALL_COUNTRIES)
    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

I want when trying to get country from project object the country to be retrieved from the cache instead of database; I know that I can cache the whole project object with all data in it but I don't want to do that I want only to get the lookup inside it from the cache

Comment: `@Cacheable` is for caching results of method calls. It will NOT cache individual entities for later retrieval on ID or whatever. Instead use the 2nd level cache of your persistence provider instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Cacheable` annotation needs to be put on Spring Beans, not entities, but I don't think it works on repositories either. You also need `@EnableCaching` in your config. Here is a good tutorial:
 [Caching Data with Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) that shows an example of that. So basically you would create something like a `CountryService` which is backed by your `CountryRepository`, and has the annotation on the Service.

**Edit** :
There is no way to get that annotation working in an entity, `@Cacheable` must be in a Spring Bean. What you could do is only save the ID of the country in the project, and use the `CountryService` which has caching to retrieve the Country, that will prevent you accessing the country tables every time you retrieve a `Project`, but if your question is only how do get `@Cacheable` working in an Entity that is no possible.

Comment: ,my caching is enabled and it works fine in repository, my question is very clear that i want it to make it work in entity